# Creating a CSS-only dropdown menu - one item disappears

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I've created a CSS-only dropdown menu for my menu in Wordpress using a tutorial on CSSwizardry (don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links). I've got it working fine on my homepage: http://www.tarawilder.com (hover over "Portfolio" to see the items "Design" and "Development").

However, when you go into an interior page, only "development" shows up and not "design". Go here: http://www.tarawilder.com/portfolio/ for an example.

Why would that be? I want to rip my hair out, I've been trying to figure this out all night.

Here is the CSS for the menu (which is technically the same on both pages)

```
#menu1 {
    height: 30px;
}

.menu {
    position:relative;
    z-index:50;
}

.menu li {
    position: relative;
}

.menu a {
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.menu ul{
    background:#fff; 
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px; 
}

.menu ul li{
    padding-top:1px; 
    float: left;
    padding-top: 10px !important;
}

.menu ul a{
    white-space:nowrap; 
}

.menu li:hover ul{ 
    left:0; 
}

.menu li:hover a{ 
}

.menu li:hover ul a{ 
    text-decoration:none;
}

.menu li:hover ul li a:hover{
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your dropdown menu is contained within #header, which has the following rule:

```
#header {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

It cuts off the rest of the menu. Consider removing the `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: That's exactly it! I knew it was something simple. Thanks Mathieu!